# Codenerix - Disable a dropdown field with foreign key using ng-readonly

Tags: python, angularjs, django

## Codenerix

Has anyone knows how to use correctly ng-readonly in a GenModelForm when coming from a sublist tab (GenList) who calls a GenCreateModal windows?

Structure is a master-detail, sublist tab has pk of master table and calls GenCreateModal with this pk argument of master table.

GenCreateModal receives pk argument in his asociated form (the mentioned GenModelForm) and can use it. The goal is to disable field with ng-disabled if pk argument of master table is filled. This way when create from another list of detail table without arguments, field can be filled with a value selecting it with the dropdown, and when coming from master table it cannot be modified and it will be assigned to master pk value.

I tried to do it that way:

First assign 'client' on GenCreateModal with:

```
def get_initial(self): 
    client = self.kwargs.get('pk', None) 
    if client: 
        self.kwargs['client'] = client 
    return self.kwargs
```

Then read it on the GenModelform with:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
    super(DetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if kwargs.get('initial', None) and kwargs['initial'].get('client', None):
        self.fields['client'].widget.attrs[u'ng-readonly'] = 'true'
```

But it do not work with dropdown fields. Field can be modified.
Cause is that in templatetags_list.py of codenerix we have:

```
def inireadonly(attrs, i):
    field = ngmodel(i)
    return addattr(attrs, 'ng-readonly=readonly_{0}'.format(field))
```

This code set ng-readonly to "true readonly_client" instead of "true" when it comes with value "true" from GenModelForm, values are concatenated.

I found a workaround with:

```
self.fields['client'].widget.attrs[u'ng-readonly'] = 'true || '
```

this way the end value will be "true || readonly_client" that result on "true" as desired when evaluated, but I think it is not the proper way.

On my personal fork of django-codenerix I have changed the function to (functions is on two py files, should change both):

```
def inireadonly(attrs, i):
    field = ngmodel(i)
    if attrs.get('ng-readonly', None) is None:
        attrs = addattr(attrs, 'ng-readonly=readonly_{0}'.format(field))
    return attrs
```

This way it respects the value when it comes filled form GenModelForm, but I'm not sure about inconveniences and collateral effects. For example when want to concatenate conditions, with that change should read old value, concatenate manually and set new value. I think it should be a better way to do it and 'ng-readonly=readonly_{0}'.format(field) should have a functionality that I haven't discovered yet. Don't want to lose it when I discover it. So I revert the change and look for another solution.

Currently I'm using

```
self.fields['client'].widget.attrs[u'ng-disabled'] = 'true'
```

and it goes OK, I'm using this way and I have no problem now, but I'm curious about the way to use ng-readonly if I need it on the future. That's because with ng-readonly we can select text on fields with the mouse for example and can not select it with ng-disabled. In some cases it could be of interest.

Has anyone knows how to use ng-readonly in a correct way?
Has anyone knows the functionality of 'ng-readonly=readonly_{0}'.format(field)?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an extra attribute to your fields in your forms. Add **{'extra': ['ng-disabled=true']}** in the field of your **GenModelForm**, inside your **__groups__** method. Example:

```
def __groups__(self):
    g = [
        (_('Info'), 12,
            ['client', 6, {'extra': ['ng-disabled=true']}],
        )
    ]
    return g
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ng-disabled** as you are doing. This is the way we do it in [Django Codenerix Example @ Gibhub](https://github.com/centrologic/django-codenerix-examples/blob/master/exchange/exchange/base/forms.py) (lines 41 and 42) and this is how it has been developed for **[StaticSelects](https://github.com/centrologic/django-codenerix/blob/master/codenerix/widgets.py)** (line 228) as well.